# URL Amigable con Nginx - problema con archivos

Tags: nginx

Intentaré ser lo mas explícito posible.

Amigos, estoy utilizando Nginx como servidor local y he estado modificando las url de manera amigable, pero tengo un problema, podrian ayudarme con esta solución? que estoy haciendo mal?

informo que todos mis proyectos estan en la carpeta www (localhost)

He logrado hacer que una url quede: `http//localhost/miproyecto/producto/1000`

Utilizando el siguiente código en nginx.conf:

```
location /miproyecto/producto/ { 
    index index.php; 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /miproyecto/producto/index.php?$args; 
}
```

Tambien eliminé todas las extenciones de los archivos.

```
http//localhost/miproyecto/busqueda.php
```

A :

```
http//localhost/miproyecto/busqueda
```

Con el siguiente código:

```
location / {
    index  index.php index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

Aquí viene el mi problema y no se como solucionarlo (Aclaro con Apache me funciona de maravilla)

En vez de esta url:

```
http//localhost/miproyecto/negocio.php?empresa=nombreEmpresa
```

Quiero que quede así:

```
http//localhost/miproyecto/nombreEmpresa
```

Logré algo utilizando este código:

```
location /miproyecto/ {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/miproyecto/(.*)+$ /miproyecto/negocio.php?$1;
    }
    index index.php 
}
```

Pero mi problema aquí es que ahora si ingreso otra url por ejemplo:

```
http//localhost/miproyecto/registro
```

No abre el archivo correspondiente, es decirm no abre a `registro.php`
sino que piensa que le estoy mandando la palabra 'registro' como variable o nombre de empresa. Tampoco me toma el **index.php** es decir si coloco

`http//localhost/miproyecto/`

No me redirecciona al archivo index.php.

Y si modifico el código a esto:

```
location /miproyecto/negocio {
    index index.php;
    rewrite ^/miproyecto/(.*)+$ /miproyecto/negocio.php?$1;
}
```

Si me reconoce las urls que mencione anteriormente pero no me permite colocarla de la forma `localhost/miproyecto/nombreEmpresa`

No me permite hacer ambas cosas.

Answer (score 1):

Si en vez de usar directorios para tus entradas `location` usaras expresiones regulares, efectivamente sería posible hacer lo que propones, dado que nginx intepreta las expresiones dándole prioridad a las más específicas por sobre las menos específicas, luego

```
location ~ ^/miproyecto/negocio {
  rewrite ^/miproyecto/(.*)+$ /miproyecto/negocio.php?$1;
}
```

tendría prioridad sobre

```
location ~ ^/miproyecto/ {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/miproyecto/(.*)+$ /miproyecto/negocio.php?$1;
    }
}
```

Pero así como lo tienes, salvo jugar con el orden en que pones las reglas no creo que puedas hacer más.

Si no te animas a usar expresiones regulares para las entradas `location` lo único que se me ocurre es sugerirte que uses otro "namespace" para nombreEmpresa:

```
location /miproyecto/empresa {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/miproyecto/(.*)+$ /miproyecto/negocio.php?$1;
    }
    index index.php 
}
```